# What should a JavaScript constructor return if it fails?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

If I have a javascript class which cannot be instantiated what should the constructor return that I can test for. The constructor always returns an object so I cannot return null if the constructor fails.

```
function SomeClass(id) {
  if(typeof(id) === 'number' {
    // This is good
    this.id = id;
  } else {
    // This is bad
    // This return is ignored and an empty object is returned
    return null;
  }
}

var a = new SomeClass('badParam');
if(a){
  // is true even though the class expects a number.
}

// Could use this check
if(a.id !== undefined){
  // Do some stuff
}
```

but it seems there should be a better way.

Comment: I would return undefined

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is probably best to throw an exception to notify the caller that the initialization failed and to take appropriate action.

Return codes are fine, but for the most part there is no motivation for the caller to implement the checks on the return code.

My advice is to break hard and break soon. This will make contract violations very evident during testing.

Answer (score 27):

Returning any *non-object* from the constructor is practically the same as exiting the constructor. (The constructor will return a new object, with a `prototype` if one was specified.)

So, returning `null`, `undefined`, or `42` from the constructor are equivalent.

Check out section 13.2.2 of the [ECMAScript spec (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) for more info.

Comment: The ECMAScript spec has changed since this response and section 13.2.2 is no longer related to this conversation.

Answer (score 19):

My first approach:

1. Don't allow a constructor to fail; consider alternatives

My second approach:

1. If a constructor fails, it must only fail because of a programming error and thus;
2. **should throw an exception** and;
3. **must not return 'a status code'** (see Emmett's answer for why returning `null` doesn't work anyway)

I have never designed a constructor (something invoked as the target of `new`) to return anything except an object of the "expected" type.

Fail fast, avoid being *too* clever, and save time debugging hard-to-find bugs.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

Use I sentinel.  I like to

```
return {invalid:true};
```

This looks clean:

```
var x = new X();
if (x.invalid) { // ...
```

(There's no way to return a non-true value from a constructor, so you can't put **new** in the conditional as you might with another language.)