# How to handle wrong constructor arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a `Foo` constructor like this:

```
function Foo(params) {
  this.x = params.x + 5;
  ...  
}
```

`Foo` is called like this:

```
var foo = new Foo(someObject);
```

I would like to check the contents of `params` in `Foo`'s constructor, and if something is wrong (e.g. `params.x` is not a number, or `params.y` is `undefined`), I would like `foo` to be `null` (which will mean that the `Foo` object wasn't created).

One option, I guess, is to throw an exception in the constructor and wrap the call for `new Foo(someObject)` with `try..catch` (or create a function like `makeFoo` that does so).

How would you suggest to handle this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should a javascript constructor return if it fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149619/what-should-a-javascript-constructor-return-if-it-fails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would throw the exception. An invalid input is an exceptional condition, throwing an exception makes sense. I wouldn't bother with the `makeFoo` wrapper; the calling code should handle it.

---

Re

> I would like `foo` to be `null` (which will mean that the `Foo` object wasn't created).

There's no way to make the expression `new Foo(...)` return `null`. Normally, the result of the `new` expression is a reference to the object that was constructed by the `new` operator and passed into the constructor function as `this`. The constructor function **can** override that and return a different object, but it can't do so by returning `null`. If the constructor function doesn't return anything, or returns something that isn't an object (not including `null`; `null` isn't an object [it has its own type, [`Null`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.2)], despite the fact that `typeof null` is `"object"`), the result of the `new` expression will be the object created by the `new` operator. More in Sections [11.2.2](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2) and [13.2.2](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2).